# Wordpress- <iframe> is incorrectly interpreting url page content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to embed a vimeo player in my Wordpress 3.8 site. To make changing the video a little easier, I've created Page which just contains the url for a Vimeo video. On the site, I try to embed the video like so:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="" src="<? echo apply_filters('the_content', get_page(925)->post_content); ?>" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

But when I view the site, it just loads an empty page template inside the frame! When I echo that php chunk outside the iframe, however, it returns the url as expected. Putting in the url directly causes it to work fine, and I've tried a ton of quotation configurations to make sure the error wasn't there. Any idea what is causing it to wig out?

Answer (score 0):

why are you running apply_filters on this? Also, get_page is deprecated.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$vidPost = get_post(925);
echo '<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="" src="'.$vidPost->post_content.'" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
?>
```